# Does Firebase JobDispatcher use JobScheduler from API level 21 up?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I've read suggestions that the [`Firebase JobDispatcher`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) makes use of [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) where available (i.e. from API level 21 and up), and otherwise uses it's own method (based on Google Play services).

For example, Google's info [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#fjd) states the following:

> Firebase JobDispatcher serves as a JobScheduler-compatibility layer for apps targeting versions of Android lower than 5.0 (API level 21).

But I've found that, for one particular user, a job in my app works fine when started via `Firebase JobDispatcher` but not via `JobScheduler`, on an Android 6.0 device.

So I thought I'd dig around the `Firebase JobDispatcher` code to see what I could find.  But I can't find any reference in the library to `JobScheduler`.  A search on the repository for this term returns no hits.

I'm a bit of a novice, so don't flame me, but can anyone here tell me whether `Firebase JobDispatcher` does in fact use `JobScheduler`, and if so point me to the bit in the library code where `JobScheduler` is used?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you are correct. The JobScheduler isn't used as of right now. The JobDispatcher can work with any Driver you want but the only Driver it comes with is the GooglePlayDriver.

If you want the JobDispatcher to use the JobScheduler you have to [wait for Google to deliver](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/32) or write your own driver.